# Spring Batch Job stopped with no obvious reason

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch simple job :

```sql
@Autowired
public JobBuilderFactory jobs;

@Bean
public Job jobTraitement(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener,
                         @Qualifier("stepOne") Step stepOne,
                         @Qualifier("stepTwo") Step stepTwo,
                         @Qualifier("stepThree") Step stepThree,
                         @Qualifier("stepFour") Step stepFour,
                         @Qualifier("stepFive") Step stepFive,
                         @Qualifier("stepSix") Step stepSix,
                         @Qualifier("stepSeven") Step stepSeven,
                         @Qualifier("stepEight") Step stepEight,
                         @Qualifier("stepNine") Step stepNine) {
    return jobs.get(ConstantesCommunes.JobNames.MY_NINESTEPS_JOB)
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .preventRestart()
            .listener(listener)
            .start(stepOne)
            .next(stepTwo)
            .next(stepThree)
            .next(stepFour)
            .next(stepFive)
            .next(stepSix)
            .next(stepSeven)
            .next(stepEight)
            .next(stepNine)
            .build();
}
```

When I execute this job on my development machine it executes all steps correctly and ends with status `COMPLETED` however in production machine (with same inputs and parameters) the job ends in `stepSix` with status `STOPPED` with no obvious reason and no errors of any kind:

```
2019-06-27 18:49:48.666  INFO 36529 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.support.SimpleJobRepository    : Parent JobExecution is stopped, so passing message on to StepExecution
2019-06-27 18:49:48.670  INFO 36529 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.AbstractJob           : Encountered interruption executing job: JobExecution interrupted.
27/Jun/2019 18:49:48.670 - {} - [main] INFO  com.package.helpers.JobCompletionNotificationListener - [my_ninesteps_job] STOPPED
```

And in the `batch_job_execution` table in database, the status is `STOPPED` and the exit message is `org.springframework.batch.core.JobInterruptedException`.

I read that [spring stopped logging that exception](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1830), so my question is : is there a way to activate logs for that exception ? Did anyone else had the same issue, what leads to follow ?

Thanks

**Update**

I'm using log4j for logging and logging level is set to debug :

```xml
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" ignoreExceptions="false">
        <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %X - [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="DEBUG">
        <AppenderRef ref="AsyncConsole"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Comment: As mentioned in the issue you linked, the stacktrace will be logged only at DEBUG log level. Can you activate the DEBUG log level (in your logging framework config) for "org.springframework.batch" package and post the full output?

Comment: try to log data processing in every step reader, processor or/and writer

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine debug is already set as log level, I updated my question.

Comment: @ValeriyK. that's what I'm doing, I can't share the hole log because it weights 400Mb. The job actually stops somewhere in the processor of `stepSix`.

Comment: According to the resolution of [BATCH-1830](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1830), you should see the stacktrace of the exception if the log is at DEBUG level. Are you sure "org.springframework.batch" is correclty logging at DEBUG level?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine yes it is.

Comment: In that case, can you post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I ran it yesterday (it takes some hours to reproduce the case) and it just stops the job and show the 3 lines of log that I shared in the question. By the way, I have listener that extends `JobExecutionListenerSupport` referenced in that job, do you think that maybe I can add some logging in `public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution)`, do you have any ideas about this ?